# Encode array to jpeg image in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, jpeg

I want to create and fill jpeg file with RGB information. why in official sources i can't find information about how to do this.
**I don't want to use any library for this.**

Comment: You totally can: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is based on a totally false premise due to utter lack of research.

Comment: i can't find information about how to save information in file with extension jpeg

Comment: That's because you are not reading the document. The file format specification is about as explicit as you can get. JPEG is pretty complex, so you will pretty much have to write your own library to deal with it if you don't want to use an existing implementation.

Comment: Here is the "backend" referenced in the document I mentioned:  Annex B
of ISO DIS 10918-1 http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf

Comment: could you elaborate why you even would want to do it without library? Since you will in fact write your own, probably less efficient library for it

Comment: You have to do fill operation over bitmap in memory. Conversion to JPEG is made when you store it to file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do it yourself, you need to read the book [http://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1450707737&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604434)
and have a copy of the JPEG standard.

Comment: where i can get a copy of the JPEG standard?

Comment: There is a DoD version of the standard that can be downloaded. MIL-STD-188-198A . It's almost identical to the for pay JPEG standard.

Also, don't ask JPEG questions using the C++ tag. The C++ folks try to run up SO points and put on hold anything they cannot answer.